# Allow css in framework

Tags: javascript, php, css, sass, frameworks

How can I allow CSS in a custom framework?
I use a framework from this video [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DpbUqJcch0Y&t=9s). But it does not allow the use of CSS, JS or any kind of files besides PHP. I have tried checking if the file contains CSS and then excluding it but that also does not work. Does anyone have any suggestions? Here is the [link to the github project](https://github.com/Piotrucci91/simpleMVC).

Comment: Please see [ask] and how to create a [mre] _within_ your question, and then try again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use HTML in PHP files

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
  <?php
require_once('Routes.php');

function __autoload($class_name)  {

      if (file_exists('./classes/'.$class_name.'.php'))
      {
        require_once './classes/'.$class_name.'.php';
      }
      else if (file_exists('./controllers/'.$class_name.'.php'))
      {
        require_once './controllers/'.$class_name.'.php';
      }
      //a  special function in php that autoloads
      //classed from ur classes folder
}
 ?>
</body>
</html>
```